# Подключение скрипта к странице

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

В расширении для google chrome указал скрипт, который выполнится на нужном мне сайте.

Этот скрипт должен подключить к странице другой файл скрипта при помощи вот такой опции в манифесте

"web_accessible_resources": [
    "somescript.js"
  ]

в скрипте этом находится класс. Подключается в итоге скрипт вот так

```
var functions = document.createElement('script');
functions.onload = function(){
    let someObject = new SomeClass(document);
    someObject.doAnything();
};
functions.src = chrome.extension.getURL('somescript.js');
functions.type = 'text\/javascript';
document.head.appendChild(functions);
```

Но это не работает. Когда срабатывает `functions.onload`, ничего не происходит а в консоль выводится

> Uncaught ReferenceError: SomeClass is not defined
>       at HTMLScriptElement.functions.onload

То есть в тот момент, когда выполняется `functions.onload`, контекст еще ничего не знает про `SomeClass`. И вот уже после этого я могу написать в консоли

```
let someObject = new SomeClass(document);
someObject.doAnything();
```

и все отрабатывает нормально. Может, мне нужно не onload событие, а какое то другое?

Comment: а что если сделать самовызывающуюся функцию? Ведь по хорошему, вам нет необходимости "ждать" onload , чтобы скрипт сработал (ведь в момент работы вашего скрипта выше, SomeClass должен быть уже доступен , а именно вызван РАНЬШЕ по списку скриптов или выше данных строчек ). А вообще вы сначала пытаетесь вызвать класс, который еще не подключен (onload срабатывает раньше чем вы appendChild). Я думаю что ответ кроется в порядке вызовов. Т.е. попробуйте подключить класс выше, чем вызывать onload (хоть он уже вам и не понадобится после )

Comment: @alexoander, functions.onload - это не вызов, а установка обработчика. По идее обработчик должен срабатывать, когда ресурс будет загружен. В играх картинки таким же образом подгружаются.

Comment: Обработчик сработает сразу же в вашем случае

Comment: @alexoander, почему?

Comment: а и да - если вы используете ES6, то при use strict вам сама среда скажет что у вас не объявлен SomeClass даже учитывая отложенный вызов посредством обработчика.

Comment: потому что https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded

Comment: @alexoander, я не знаю что такое ES6. Обработчик сработает тогда, когда будет вызвано onload во внутренностях ява скрипта. В общем даже после того, как я поставил его после appendChild, ничего не поменялось

Comment: @alexoander, я больше скажу, если я закомментирую `document.head.appendChild(functions);` или `functions.src = ...`, то onload не выполнится. Значит onload выполняется именно после загрузки ресурсов (в данном случае файла с яваскриптом).

Comment: @alexoander, единственное ,что приходит в голову, это то, что в контексте функции, которую я указываю в onload, нет доступа к моему классу. Но как это проверить не знаю. Как добраться до основного контекста?

Answer (score 0):

Фактически, я сказал абсолютно тоже самое - в onload нет SomeClass потому что ты его добавляешь "после" объявления обработчика... забудь ты про onload для начала. После добавления somescript..js в разметку, someClass должен быть доступен везде. Что по сути ведет к следующему -

```
....
let functions = document.createElement('script');
functions.src = chrome.extension.getURL('somescript.js');
functions.type = 'text\/javascript';
document.head.appendChild(functions);
// незачем onload если SomeText уже будет доступен после добавления в документ 
let someObject = new SomeClass(document);
someObject.doAnything();
....
```

Comment: Аналогично. Получаю Uncaught ReferenceError: SomeClass is not defined. Что не удивительно, ведь операция `document.head.appendChild(functions);` выполняется асинхронно.

Comment: а раз она выполняется асинхронно (что в принципе я не знал - спасибо! ) то значит и управлять ею надо как асинхронным вызовом через .then() и promise. Т.е. дожидаемся добавления кода в сайт и только потом оперируем новым классом